# How to check for one date is less than or equal another date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am having a difficult time checking if one date is less than or equal to another.

Here is my code,

```
var bftStartDt = input1[0]; //This is a string with value "01-Jul-2007"
var bftEndDt = input1[4]; //This is a string with value "01-Jul-1942"

var strtDt = new Date(bftStartDt);
var endDt = new Date(bftEndDt);
var flag = 0; // false

if (endDt <= strtDt){
   flag = 1; // true
}
```

It never enters the if statement when it should ? What am I missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that you're actually constructing valid Date instances from your strings?

Comment: No - How do i do that ?

Comment: Before the `if` add `console.log("start: " + strtDt + " end: " + endDt);` and make sure they look OK.

Comment: While you're at it, `console.log(bftStartDt, bftEndDt);` to ensure the strings really contain what you think they do.

Comment: Never mind - I just noticed your sample date format. JavaScript won't be able to parse that directly. You may want to look into the Moment.js library.

Comment: And please do `var flag=endDt <= strtDt;` when you have tested with `windows.console&&console.log(strtDt);`

Comment: It looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/haf5Ld2v/

Comment: Works in Chrome, but not IE or FF for me.  Don't trust that date format.  Use one of the standard ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var strtDt  = new Date("2007-07-01");
var endDt  = new Date("1942-07-01");
var flag = 0; // false

if (endDt <= strtDt){
   flag = 1; // true
   alert("true");
}
```

It works check out the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/20pyBTPnjwlc2vHhW8qu?p=info)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius corrected it now works on FF

Comment: Oh good. Deleting both my comments then...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `01-Jul-2007` is not a format supported by the `Date` object. Try doing `2007-01-07` instead. Then your program works as expected.

```
var bftStartDt = "01-07-2007"; //This is a string with value "01-Jul-2007"
var bftEndDt = "01-07-1942"; //This is a string with value "01-Jul-1942"

var strtDt = new Date(bftStartDt);
var endDt = new Date(bftEndDt);
var flag = 0; // false

if (endDt <= strtDt){
   flag = 1; // true
}

if(flag === 1) {
  console.log("It worked.");
}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), the accepted formats are:

> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

So you could also use the format `Jul 01 2007`. The full list of formats is in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14).

Comment: How to handle format "DD MON, YYYY" which is got by date picker?